# ZMQ: how to bind from the REP side in DEALER/REP or REQ/REP socket

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I want to setup a topology where a worker's IP address is unknown, but only a central broker's address is known. Thus I am trying to bind with a dealer, and connect with rep. But rep never gets my messages:

Using Python3.

Process 1:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
sock = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
sock.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:55597")
```

Process 2:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
sockrep = context.socket(zmq.REP)
sockrep.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:55597")
```

Now if I send a message from Process 1:

```
sock.send(b"hello")
```

Process 2 locks up:

```
sockrep.recv() #..............blocks forever
```

Is there any way I can make the above pattern work? Am I in need of other socket types or another topology? I can get it working fine with DEALER DEALER but then I have two fully async sockets and that's not what I want. To reiterate, there is only ONE known IP address and that is the one of the computer making the *requests*, not those filling the requests (these have to connect to the binded requestor).

Answer (score 2):

When sending from `DEALER` to `REP` you need to prefix your message with an empty frame (as `REP` has support for messages that have been through `ROUTER` sockets, so it strips of all frames until the empty frame)

Comment: so how do I send this? sock.send(["", "hello"]) ?

Comment: i think its something like : `sock.send_multipart([b"", b"hello"])` but I've never used the python api.